# htaccess rewrite rule for page/title in wordpress?

Tags: apache, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am creating one little plugin for WordPress which is about trips.
I am now at the point to create a browse page where to be opened each trip.

My idea is this -
I have created `http://example.com/?page_id=143`

And i want at my site users to open page as  : `http://example.com/trip/NAME`

Can someone help me with the rewrite url? because I am very weak on rewriting..

Comment: How the name relates to an id? /trip/name => page_id=1

Comment: ops I have missed  > ?page_id=143&name=NAME

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this before your wordpress rules and after the `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^trip/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ index.php?page_id=143&name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: now when I go to page `/trip/tripname` it redirects me to `/?page_id=143`
It shouldn't redirect..

Comment: again - redirect to page_id=143

Comment: what's your full .htaccess looks like? maybe you have a conflicting rule

Comment: I was able to finish it . Thank you for your help :)